# JavaScript why the 'this' isn't binded correctly

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Take a look at this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/2aLht10r/1/
[image]

You can see that I am getting `undefined` when what I want is to get `B`.
For some reason, the this in line 11 is `undefined` where it should be the this of the `a` object created in line 17 (within class `B`).

What is wrong with my code?

Here is the fiddle code:

```
class A {
  selector;
  ui = {
    selector: `${this.selector} aaa`
  }

  constructor(selector) {
    this.selector = selector;
  }

  clog = console.log.bind(null, this.ui.selector)
}

class B {
  selector;
  ui = {
    a: new A('B')
  }

  print = this.ui.a.clog.bind(this.ui.a);
}

new B().print();
```

Comment: I see no code. Just a screenshot and a link.

Comment: there is a fiddle

Comment: It's surprising that someone with 3k rep doesn't know this already but ok...if your code isn't _here_, as text, it may as well be invisible.

Comment: @adeneo, I don't think that I understand you

Comment: Why it should ?

Comment: @Clive, I am surprised too :) (thanks)

Comment: Very welcome :) Hopefully the downvoter(s) will see this and get a chance to retract the votes

Comment: Did you mean `(new B()).print();`

Comment: @TheReason, you right (let me correct the code)

Comment: @Jonathan, it is the same. Try yourself.

Comment: Checkout the updated code, added binding at line 28

Comment: That's not ES6. Are you using any experimental transpiler plugins?

Comment: This is transpiled with babel

Comment: Yes, but what preset are you using? It's a syntax error in ES2015 and ES2016

Comment: Take a look at the fiddle. There are no errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ordering of operations is tripping you up.

```
class A {
  selector;
  ui = {
    selector: `${this.selector} aaa`
  }

  constructor(selector) {
    this.selector = selector;
  }
}
console.log(new A("thing").ui.selector)
```

prints `undefined aaa` as you said because it is equivalent to this:

```
class A {
  constructor(selector) {
    this.ui = {
      selector: `${this.selector} aaa`
    };

    this.selector = selector;
  }
}
console.log(new A("thing").ui.selector);
```

so your `ui` property stores `this.selector + 'aaa'` before it has been assigned the value passed into the constructor.

Perhaps you'd be better off doing this:

```
class A {
  ui = {
    selector: null,
  };

  constructor(selector) {
    this.ui.selector = `${selector} aaa`;
  }
}
console.log(new A("thing").ui.selector)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error. Can you suggest other a way to be able to use the value passed though the constructor and use it then later (in the clog function)?

Comment: Added another snippet. Really though, I'm not not clear on why you're using classes here at all. You'd probably be better off having a normal function that just returns an object, at least given your examples.

Comment: You would also need to move the `clog` function inside the constructor i think. If the properties depend on the arguments passed down to the constructor then I guess it's just better to have them in the constructor.

Comment: "*Perhaps you'd be better off*" …just moving everything inside the constructor, as it is expected in ES6?

Comment: @Bergi Yeah, that too, but I figured I'd try to keep it along the lines of the original code where possible.